# Is it there a way to use one URI for multiple routes?

Tags: laravel, callback, routes, payment, gateway

I am using paystack payment gateway to receive a response using a callback function in my controller if the payment is successful, I have two ways to make payment on the site, one is through the site's store/shop and one through donation, which is working fine with a single route URI name which is /paystack/callback, the problem is when tried to use the same URI name to receive donation payment response it doesn't work, and when I check the route list only one URI with the name paystack/callback is listed.

**This is my Route**

// PAYMENT PROCESSING AND RETURN RESPONSE

```
Route::post('/pay', 'CheckOutController@redirectToGateway')->name('payment');
Route::get('/payment/callback', 'CheckOutController@handleGatewayCallback');



// DONATION PAYMENT PROCESSING AND RETURN RESPONSE

Route::get('/donation', function () {  return view('donation'); })->name('donation');
Route::post('/donation', 'DonationController@redirectToGateway')->name('donate');
Route::get('/payment/callback', 'DonationController@store');
```

so my question is, is there a way to use that URI name for both payment response because that is the URI I used on the payment gateway website in my dashboard

[image: dashboard screenshot]

Comment: you would have to have 1 route and you would have to distinguish these 2 different types of requests coming in

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a middleware to get it. In this way, you direct the request to one or the other controller depending on the type of response you receive from your payment platform (donation or payment, I imagine that the values received are different).

1. Create a middleware in app/Http/middleware with this structure:

```html
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
        
        use Closure;
        use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
        
        class PaymentDonation{
        
            public function handle($request, Closure $next)
            {
                //Any variable contained in the response of your 
                //gateway that indicates if it is payment.
                if ($request->xxxxx) 
                {
                    return $next($request);
                }
                //Else if response indicates donation...
                return new RedirectResponse(url('/payment/callbackDonation'));
            }
        
        }
```

2. Declare your middleware in app/Kernel.php

```html
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // some other middlewares
        'paymentdonation' => 'App\Http\Middleware\PaymentDonation',
    ];
```

3. Two routes:

```html
    Route::middleware('paymentdonation')->get('/payment/callback', 'CheckOutController@handleGatewayCallback');
    Route::get('/payment/callbackDonation', 'DonationController@store');
```

My code is not tested but it can serve as an approximation.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, the value recieved are the same there variable from the response to diffrerentiate between purchase payment and donation.

Comment: I even and add some info in the metadata of the form hoping to use it to differentiate between donation and payment, the request body only contains a header, server info etc...

Comment: I do not know how the api works, but if there is no difference between the two response codes, you will not be able to establish different action mechanisms for each type of operation, unless before sending the payment request you can save an operation identifier that you know in advance will be contained in the response and then relate it.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved, I used one controller and then use condition to check for a unique variable that I added when submitting the payment if it is equal to donation or purchase and base on that perform the needed action.